# How work wih Oracle from C++ .net

Tags: .net, oracle, c++-cli

When i try compile my code i have error

> error C3673: Oracle::DataAccess::Client::OracleDataReader:  the class has no copy constructor

And  i can't find OracleDataReader component. There is code

```
    Form1(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        String^ ConStr = "User Id=user;Password=password;" +
                        "Data Source=db;";
        oracleConnection1->ConnectionString= ConStr;
        oracleConnection1->Open();  

        oracleCommand1->Connection= oracleConnection1;
        oracleCommand1->CommandText = "select * from sometable";
        oracleCommand1->CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        oracleCommand1->ExecuteNonQuery();
                OracleDataReader data= gcnew  Oracle::DataAccess::Client::OracleCommand() ;
        data  = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    }
```

Can anyone tell what i'm doing wrong?

P.S. I use VS Express Edition.

Comment: You are trying to create object of an class which is not copyable, a.k.a: you are not supposed to create any copies of it' object.

Comment: this may be because you should not instantiate OracleDataReader directly rather store the resultset from executereader direct to the DataReader Object

Comment: and one thing surprising me that you are passing a reference of OracleCommand object to DataReader object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Form1(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        String^ ConStr = "User Id=user;Password=password;" +
                        "Data Source=db;";
        oracleConnection1->ConnectionString= ConStr;
        oracleConnection1->Open();  
        Oracle::DataAccess::Client::OracleCommand oracleCommand1 = gcnew Oracle::DataAccess::Client::OracleCommand(oracleConnection1); 
        // get query results
        oracleCommand1->Connection= oracleConnection1;
        oracleCommand1->CommandText = "select * from sometable";
        oracleCommand1->CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        OracleDataReader _OracleDataReader = _oracleCommand1->ExecuteReader();

    }
```